# What is a Wyrrd™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>In honor of the long-running [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles,  came up with this puzzle myself.</sub>

There's a special rule that can be applied to words to determine whether or not they're a Wyrrd™. Here are some examples:

| Wyrrd™ | Not a Wyrrd™ |
| --- | --- |
| efficient | late |
| halved | complete |
| odd | even |
| adjacent | final |
| inefficient | flawless |
| versatile | mediocre |

If you want the CSV to analyze, here it is:

```
Wyrrd™,Not a Wyrrd™
efficient,late
halved,complete
odd,even
adjacent,final
inefficient,flawless
versatile,mediocre
```

What is the rule that determines whether something is a Wyrrd™? Bonus: figure out why it's called a Wyrrd™.

Comment: Two hypotheses, one is that "Wyrrd" has no I and e, another is that a lot of the left ones end with t and d

Comment: Hints? @Deter...

Comment: @NumberBasher Hold your horses - this puzzle has only just been posted! :) Convention on Puzzling is to wait at least 24 hours before dropping hints, as this is a global community - it gives our users from all around the world a chance to see it and contribute. It's worth noting that in this type of puzzle the title itself is usually a carefully chosen hint - start with that....

Comment: @NumberBasher By the way, it's "De r ter", not "Deter" (it has an "r").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Wyrrd is a word that

> Has been the subject of, and in the title of, a previous word puzzle by yours truly. The rot13 of wyrrd is Jleeq, meaning a JLee question (thx Auribouros)

I thought on this puzzle for 2 hours and tried many dead ends, and then it hit me!

Thanks for the puzzle!

Comment: Also want to add why it's named Wyrrd, ybh zvtug jnag gb EBG13 gur zvqqyr guerr yrggre :)

Comment: All correct, and I'm glad you enjoyed it ;-)!